# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'max_columns'

Tags: python, dataframe

May I know what this error is about?
What is not right here?
I've followed the instruction here https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-display-full-dataframe-i-e-print-all-rows-columns-without-truncation/.
But the following error (snapshot) is generated after running the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

pd.options.display.max_rows
# Default value of display.max_rows is 10 i.e. at max 10 rows will be printed.
# Set it None to display all rows in the dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

display.max_columns
# Set it to None to display all columns in the dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

[image]

Comment: Please give your reproducable code snippets (not screenshots) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be in a jupyter notebook, `display` is a function from `IPython.core`. You don't seem to have specified another variable called `display`, so you're looking for the attribute `max_columns` of this function. But functions don't have that attribute. Assign what you want the max_columns of to another variable and try again.

I also agree that you should provide a code example. But from looking at the link, you're trying to run as a function what is supposed to be an option for `pandas`. From the link: `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is resolved after correcting the second last statement to

```
pd.options.display.max_columns
# Set it to None to display all columns in the dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```